# Material design inverse spinner/edittext theme using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm having issues creating a Material Design app with the AppCompat v21 theme. First I have my app theme using the AppCompat light with dark actionbar.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_color_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_accent</item>
</style>
```

The color branding for my app is quite dark which is why I use the DarkActionBar variant. My problem is that I have a couple layouts where I'd like to put a `Spinner` and an `EditText` inside a layout where the background is my `theme_color` which is dark. This results in a `Spinner/EditText` with black color on a dark background. How can I make the style/theme of these controls use the Dark variant so they show up with white text instead of black text. Even worse than that, I need the spinner to show white text but dropdown items of the spinner to show the light version.

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView hasn't been styled yet - see here for more details: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77742

Answer (score 0):

How about this..

make a style for you widget, ex:

```
<style name="CustomEditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

then in your xml add this attribute to your EditText

```
style="@style/CustomEditText"
```

Comment: I could but this would most likely result in some frankenstein controls. I mean it would be better to use the dark control of AppCompat. Cause it that case everything would be skinned properly.  I just don't know how to use AppCompat dark just for a couple controls

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Spinner inside a Toolbar with dark background and remembered that the Google I/O Android App does the same, so I looked at its styles - more specifically, the ActionBarThemeOverlay [here](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml).

After I used the below attributes on my theme, my Spinner background color (the "arrow") changed:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">#3fff</item>
```

colorControlHighlight is the color when the user presses the Spinner. I didn't test on an EditText, though.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're looking for a way to apply a different theme to select views.
There's no xml-only way to do that for most elements (except `Toolbar`, which you already know)

You'll have to inflate the views manually, using a `ContextThemeWrapper`:

```
ContextThemeWrapper wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),
    R.style.Theme_AppCompat); // The dark one
LayoutInflater footPump = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).cloneInContext(wrapper);
// Note null as second argument -- if you pass in parent view, theme will
// be taken from the parent
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) footPump.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
```

to have the layout resource for the inflater, just create a single-view xml file:

```
<!-- res/layout/spinner.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```